# REST API Layered Authorization

Tags: rest, web, access-control

I have an HTTP REST API that built for one of my company's devices. Ideally, the customer would have access to certain APIs, company employees would have more access, developers would have full access. Think of the device as a router - the customer can access certain settings, employees can come in and access more APIs than the customer for troubleshooting, and developers can access everything.

What are some good methods for implementing layered authorization on a REST API? Send an Authorization token or something in a POST so you can get an authorization cookie before using the REST API? I'm not familiar enough with web security to know a clunky solution from an elegant one.

Answer (score 0):

you will send an authorization token in your Http Request header

Header.Add("Authorization", "bearer your_token")